# Не могу запустить jar файл

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Пытался сделать телеграмм бота, мавеном запихнул все в jar, запускаю, выдает эту ошибку

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/generics/LongPollingBot

Изначально была еще подобная ошибка, но ее я исправил тем что убрал неиспользуемый но импортированный класс, LongPollingBot я тоже когда-то импортировал по ошибке, но потом все его "следы" удалил, а ошибка все равно есть.

Error: Unable to initialize main class com.telegram.client.MyClasses.Main

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/generics/LongPollingBot

main class:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;


public class Main extends Thread{
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Telegram());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
      
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Возможно класс org/telegram/telegrambots/generics/LongPollingBot всё еще используется в вашем коде, но при сборке jar не был туда добавлен, нужно пересобрать jar со всеми зависимостями. По поводу удалил все следы: если вы используете telegrambots-spring-boot-starter возможно класс все равно инстанциируется при старте приложения.

Comment: @АндрейГородецкий я провел поиск, нигде в проекте следов нет

Comment: @АндрейГородецкий импортируется TelegramLongPooling но это уже другой класс